# Strange JSON.parse() error in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, v8

I'm retrieving some stringifyed JSON via TCP in node.js an want to parse it. So my approach is similiar to this. I shortend and simplified it, so you don't have to know the surrounding logic.

```
socket.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());               // Shows the original stringifyed version
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()));   // Doesn't work
});
```

The complete (beautified) JSON is this. As you can see, there are no errors.

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "source": "chat",
    "success": {
        "message": "test",
        "time": 1331770513,
        "player": "silvinci"
    }
}
```

But `JSON.parse(data.toString())` always throws me this dumb error:

```
{"result":"success","source":"console","success":{"time":1331762264,"line":"20
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/node/api.js:152:35)    // irrelevant from here on
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:347:14)
```

So I thougt: "What could be wrong with the JSON-String. Let's try it directly. Should not work." Surprise, Surprise! It worked. Why does it work when I directly enter the String?

Comment: Did you actually run the shortened and simplified code?

Comment: Maybe the stream contains some weird control characters... is `data` a string or already the parsed object (or something else)?

Comment: @FelixKling has a good point.  What is `data.toString().charCodeAt(0)`?

Comment: You are right, and I'm dumb. There is one line break hidden inside the JSON, that wasn't encoded the right way.

Comment: @silvinci, ah.  Regular CR LF are okay (RFC 4627 2.), but it might have been something like a BOM.

Comment: Btw i noticed that 1331770513 is without quotes "", i doubt this will conform to JSON standards.

Comment: @ChinBoon, it's fine, since it's a number.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to @[Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) I found my bug. It's very important to filter unescaped characters, especially outside the stringified JSON. I didn't and overlooked an invisible linebreak right after the stringified JSON.

This is the fix:

```
socket.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());                          // Shows the original stringified version
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString().slice(0, -4))); // Trim the sequence "\r\n" off the end of the string
});
```

Please note, that this *only* works for me, as I have a very specialized case. The server is always responding in lines of JSON, that are terminated with an `\r\n` - not the whitespace characters, but literally backslash r and backslash n.
Your code may (or probably) fail due to other errors. But checking the server's response is a good starting point when you get parsing errors.

As @[Zack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023113/zack) correctly pointed out, this is a more general fix for removing unintended whitespace:

```
JSON.parse(data.toString().trim());
```

Comment: Not knowing the context, it seems a little dangerous to unconditionally truncate the string.  Maybe you should add a test for the offending characters before slicing.

Comment: In my case every response is terminated with `\r\n`. But you're right in general, so I appended a notice.

Comment: If you're seeing this issue and would like a more general solution use something like:

`JSON.parse(data.toString().trim());`

String.prototype.trim will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Zack yep! Added it to the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.  For a more general solution, this will work too.  It takes off all whitespace before and after the string so you don't have to do the specific substring length.

```
JSON.parse(data.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of blindly removing last 4 chars, I suggest to remove the offending chars only:

```
socket.on("data", function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString()); // Shows the original stringified version
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString().replace('\t','').replace('\r','').replace('\n',''))); // Trim the sequence "\r\n" off the end of the string
});
```

Comment: I've replaced `\t` too.  `conf = JSON.parse(confData.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').replace('\t',''));`